# Xamarin android invalid uri exception

Tags: android, xamarin.android, httpwebrequest, uri

In my Xamarin android application I need to make an api call to openweathermap to get current weather data according to the user's current location.

Here is my query string code:

```
url = "api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=" +
                                _currentLocation.Latitude +
                                "&lon=" +
                                _currentLocation.Longitude +
                                "&APPID=" + openWeatherAPIKey
                                                + "&units=imperial";
```

Now in the method FetchUrlAsync I send the web request and retrieve the response json. Below is the code of the method:

```
async Task<JsonValue> FetchUrlAsync(string url)
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(new System.Uri(url));
        request.ContentType = "application/json";
        request.Method = "GET";

        using (WebResponse response = await request.GetResponseAsync())
        {
            // Get a stream representation of the HTTP web response:
            using (System.IO.Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
            {
                // Use this stream to build a JSON document object:
                JsonValue jsonDoc = await Task.Run(() => JsonObject.Load(stream));
                Console.Out.WriteLine("Response: {0}", jsonDoc.ToString());

                // Return the JSON document:
                return jsonDoc;
            }
        }
    }
```

I get a System.URIFormatException thrown on the first line of the method because the format of the uri is wrong. I checked other stack overflow questions and I think it might be because my url string does not start with a http:// or ftp. But I can't add http:// or ftp in front of the url string because that leads to an unrecognized server.

Any solution to this issue? Or does it not have to do with adding the http:// or ftp prefix?

Comment: A URL is not a URL without a protocol. How is removing a part to get to another error any fix? Just make it into a proper URL and if you get an error investigate that.

Comment: Sorry what part did I remove?

Comment: The protocol. If it's http it needs to have that in front of it.

Comment: Alright. I never had it in the first place, it was working without it for some reason, but yes your right I will add it and see what errors come up.